# Checking if a time falls within a time range in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I know this can be accomplished on the backend - but I'm wondering if there's any native, or efficient MySQL function that can be used to check if a given `time` variable falls within a range covered by two `time` variables (a `start_time`, and an `end_time`).

I have a database currently set up which looks like the following;

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+
| id | job_id | start_time | end_time |
+----+--------+------------+----------+
|  1 |     40 | 13:00:00   | 14:00:00 |
|  2 |     44 | 14:45:00   | 15:00:00 |
|  3 |     45 | 15:10:00   | 15:30:00 |
+----+--------+------------+----------+
```

The backend accepts a `start_time`, and an `end_time` with a `job_id` - and then it looks to see if it can be fit in anywhere. So for example, given a start_time of `13:30:00`, and an end_time of `13:45:00`, the backend should reject this job request as there is no time available for it (it would overlap with the entry at `id 1`.)

However, if a job is submitted with a start_time of `14:10:00`, and an end time of `14:20:00`, it should be accepted - as this does not overlap with any existing tasks.

The following query is great to tell if a job can be submitted for say, 13:00:00 until 14:00:00 (an exact duplicate of id 1);

```
SELECT * WHERE start_time >= '13:00:00' AND end_time <= '14:00:00';
```

But if the start_time becomes 13:01:00, then the query falls down - as the start_time is less than 13:01:00, at 13:00:00. So it'll get approved for insertion, as the above query will return no overlapping results.

If we change the query to an `OR` clause on `end_time`, then literally any job that doesn't end before 14:00:00 would be rejected.

Can anyone suggest a simple way of taking an input variable of a `time` type, and checking if it falls within range of all available `start_time`, and `end_time` variables as noted in the db above?

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE start_time <= '14:00:00' AND end_time >= '13:00:00';` - But you probably want `<` and `>` instead of `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: @lurker Yes, if any project ends before it starts, then we're all in trouble.

Comment: @Strawberry Though "I need it by yesterday" is quite common.

Comment: Why don't you use "BETWEEN" function?

Comment: @slon That wouldn't be terribly useful.

Comment: @Strawberry It depends how you use it, if it's for you terrible, doesn't mean it's useful. You just haven't used it in right way.

Comment: @slon Or maybe it's just not terribly useful in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check in in one of the following ways: hours/minutes/seconds

```
SELECT *  FROM timetableTemp 
WHERE HOUR(TIMEDIFF(start_time, end_time))>=1 
AND start_time >=start_time
```

OR use BETWEEN function

```
SELECT *  FROM timetableTemp 
WHERE '13:00:00' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
```

support:

```
SELECT SECOND(TIMEDIFF("13:10:11", "13:10:10")) AS Seconds; -- 1
SELECT MINUTE(TIMEDIFF("13:10:11", "13:10:10")) AS Minutes; -- 0
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF("13:00:00", "14:00:00")) AS Hours; -- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a new job with start of `new_start` and end of `new_end`. Assume your existing list is in order of time of each job entry, and they are all non-overlapping.

What you'd need to check to see if the new job fits in the list without overlap would be:

- `new_end` is less than the `start_time` of the first list entry, in
  which case the new entry fits at the beginning, OR
- `new_start` is
  greater than the `end_time` of the last list entry, in which case the
  new entry fits at the end, OR
- For some in-between list entry,
  `new_start` is greater than the `end_time` and `new_end` is less than
  the `start_time` of the following list entry, in which case the new
  entry fits in between this entry and the next.